# Dynamic creation of argument names

Tags: r, function, parameters, parameter-passing

Is it possible in R to create argument names in a function call dynamically?

For example, if we start with

```
name <- "variable"
```

I would like to create a new data frame like this

```
a.new.data.frame <- data.frame(name = c(1, 2))
```

which of course does not work.

The only solution I could invent was

```
arg <- list(c(1, 2))
names(arg) <- name
a.new.data.frame <- do.call(data.frame, arg)
a.new.data.frame
#  variable
#1        1
#2        2
```

I don't like this code, since it seems not to be elegant.

Is there a better way to do it?

PS Important! This is a more general problem I have when writing R-programmes (e.g. when I use ggplot, and many other cases). So, I expect general solutions to this (creation of data.frame is only an example).

Comment: `as.data.frame(setNames(list(1:2), name))` or `setNames(data.frame(1:2), name)`

Comment: Could you please add second example with the expected result that is not resulting in a `data.frame` (to clarify the idea behind "general solution"). THX :-)

Answer (score 2):

A more compact code for dynamic args could look like this:

```
df <- do.call(data.frame, list(name = c(1, 2)))
```

You could use the `?dotsMethods` to encapsulate the `do.call` in a generic function like this to save the noisy `list()` part of the call:

```
call.with.dyn.args <- function(f, ...) {
  args <- list(...)
  do.call(f, args)
}

df1 <- call.with.dyn.args(data.frame, a = 1:2, b = letters[1:2])
df1
# a b
# 1 1 a
# 2 2 b
```

But you also have other options for dynamic argument passing to functions without a `do.call`, eg.:

```
dyn.values <- c(1:2)
name = "dyn.values"
df2 <- data.frame(dyn.values,                     # values from a variable
                  name = dyn.values,              # values from a variable + new name
                  static.arg = letters[1:2],      # usual direct passing of an arg
                  name.from.variable = get(name)) # get the values from a variable whose name is stored in another variable
df2
#   dyn.values name static.arg name.from.variable
# 1          1    1          a                  1
# 2          2    2          b                  2
```

Comment: This first code does not solve the problem, since variable in the resulting data frame has name "name".

Comment: You are right, I will drop this proposal, I have ignored your requirement that the column name shall come from a variable

Answer (score 1):

An option using `tidyverse`

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
tibble(!! name := c(1, 2))
# A tibble: 2 x 1
#  variable
#     <dbl>
#1        1
#2        2
```

Comment: Looks interesting. However, the problem I mentioned occurs not only when I try to create a new data.frame. This is a recurring problem with many functions I use (e.g. ggplot, and many more functions where I need to use dynamic variable names)